# Not able to convert xml with not bound namespase to java object, Also i can not do any changes in XML

Tags: java

XML file templated generated from some other code

```
File xmlFile = new File("example.xml");

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(detail.class);

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
detail d = (detail) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);

Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(d, System.out);
```

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/varsh/IdeaProjects/XmlConversion/example.xml;
>   lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 14; The prefix "ns2" for element
>   "ns2:details" is not bound.]  at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)

Comment: sample xml : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:details>
<ns2:firstname>varsha</ns2:firstname>
<ns2:lastname>water</ns2:lastname>
<ns2:contact>
<ns1:phone>123456789</ns1:phone>
</ns2:contact>
</ns2:details>

Answer (score 0):

Remove prefix ns2 from all the tags or specify link to xsd in xml tag, as given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<ns2:details xmlns="http://www.example.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="./example1.xsd">
     <ns2:firstname>varsha</ns2:firstname> 
    <ns2:lastname>water</ns2:lastname> 
    <ns2:contact> 
             <ns1:phone>123456789</ns1:phone>
    </ns2:contact> 
</ns2:details>
```